# pixel shader behaves strange when using variable

Tags: specular

MY problem is that when I calculate and add specular light from a point light, then it's fine if I hardcode in a number in the pixel shader, but if that number comes from a variable (it's the exponent), then the result is blocky, very sharp contrast between shadows and light.

This is my pixel shader code:

```
  cbuffer lights :register(b0)
{
row_major float4x4 worldM;
row_major float4x4 TransformM;
float4 PointLightpos;
float4 PointLightcolor;
float4 AmbientLightColor;
float4 intensities;
float4 attenuations;
float4 cameraPos;
float4 ambient;
float4 diffuse;
float4 specular;

row_major float4x4 skinMatrix[50];




  };

  Texture2D tex : register(t0);
   Texture2D nTex: register(t1);
  SamplerState mySampler : SAMPLER;

 struct Input {

float4 outPos : SV_POSITION;
float3 Color : COLOR;
float3 normal : NORMAL;
float2 UV : TEXCOORD;
float4 worldPos : POSITION;
float3 tangents : TANGENT;
};

struct Output
{
float4 Color : SV_TARGET;
};



Output main(Input input)
{
Output output;





//* ambientspecularExp 

//pointLightDiffuse
float4 plight = PointLightcolor * intensities.y;




float4 pointLightDir = normalize(PointLightpos - input.worldPos);












float4 normalW = float4(input.normal.x, input.normal.y, input.normal.z, 1);


float4 diffuseFactor = max(dot(pointLightDir, normalW), 0);


//Atten = 1/( att0i + att1i * d + att2i * d²)

float d = distance(PointLightpos, input.worldPos);

float attenuation = 1 / (attenuations.x + (attenuations.y * d) + (attenuations.z * pow(d, 2)));

float4 aL = (AmbientLightColor * intensities.x)*attenuation;

//diffuseFactor *= attenuation;

float4 diffuseLight = (plight  *diffuseFactor * diffuse)*attenuation;

//Specular * PointLightcolor

float r = reflect(-pointLightDir, normalW);

float v = normalize(cameraPos - input.worldPos);




//float4 spec = float4(max((pow(dot(r, v), specularExp) * specular), 0));
float4 spec = float4(((pow(dot(r, v), intensities.z) * specular))*attenuation);
```

Comment: Please try formatting code you post a little bit - proper indents, no long empty line sequences, drop commented code, etc.

Comment: my plan is to rewrite the code once I get it to work but thanks.